# Editng gem Ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ransack

**How I can edit gem Ransack ?**

as I know the steps are :

1. unpack gem (done)
2. modify the code as require (done)
3. build the gem ( *got problem* )

   how to build gem ransack which I modified ?

   I am refering this http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page29

   in cmd project root dir I typed : 
   gem build ransack.gemspec

   *got error :  couldn`t find file ransack.gemspec*

**solution please...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fork it on [github](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) then you've got `ransack.gemspec` file

Comment: I have already this file in unpacked gem folder still it gives me an error... thats the problem...